# Get match for java regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm a newbie to java and regex and I wanted to know if the matched regex is "A" or "OO" or "NC". I am comparing it to a textfile. I read other threads and tried them but I can't do it right. I also have a problem on my main method saying unreported exception please help.

UserLogin.java

```
public static String userLoginVerify(String actNum,String pass) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner scan = null;
    AtmMenu atm = new AtmMenu();
    try {   
            scan = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("atm\\atmstatus.flat")));
            while(scan.hasNext())
            {   
                String lines;
                lines = scan.nextLine();
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A]||[OO]||[NC]");

                        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(lines);

                if(matcher.find()) {
                    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));    
                    }
            }

    }catch(FileNotFoundException filenotfound)
        {
            System.out.println("File \"atmstatus.flat\" can't be found!");
        }       
    finally
    {   
        if(scan != null)
        scan.close();
        return "me";
    }
}
```

mainmethod here

```
public static void main(String[] login) 
{   
    passLoginInfo(login[0],login[1]);   

}

public static void passLoginInfo(String accountNumber, String password)
{
    UserLogin userLogin = new UserLogin();  
    userLogin.userLoginVerify(accountNumber, password);

}
```

Here'd the file I'm checking

```
currentamount               | stat
P500,000,000,000,000,000.00 | A
```

I am checking the letter on the stat

Comment: It's very unclear what you want to do with the regex - but in terms of the exception issue - how much do you understand checked exceptions? You should read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: Do you just want to check if a string is either "A", "OO", or "NC"?

Comment: Yes I wanted to check if it matches with either of the String. I'll post the file I'm checking

Answer (score 0):

if it is only about A, OO and NC then you can have regex as:

```
?.*\\s*A|OO|NC\\s*.*$
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem and here's what I did:

```
scan = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("atm\\atmstatus.flat")));
            while(scan.hasNext())
            {   
                String lines;
                lines = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println(lines[2]);
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A]|[OO]|[NC]");             
                        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(lines);                                               
                if(matcher.find()) {
                    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));    
                    }
            }
```

Comment: Actually, that won't work as intended. The pattern `"[A]|[OO]|[NC]"` Will match the Strings `"A"`, `"O"`, `"N"` and `"C"` but not `"OO"` or `"NC"`. That's because `[]` describes a class of characters, so it would be "One of the letters in my class." What you actually want is `"(A)|(OO)|(NC)"`.